# Not getting correct data from span

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I've been making a custom user handler for Jessecar's SteamBot, which is unrelated to the problem I'm having, but essentially what I've done, is I've made it so you can set the bot to play a specific game by App ID, and I've been using this to idle on games for Steam Trading Cards, the only issue is, the only way I can check if it's finished, is by checking its inventory and how many cards are supposed to drop, which isn't too much of a hassle, but the main reason I created this was for efficiency, and doing this every time kind of defeats the purpose of it.

Because of this, I tried getting data from the badge page for the bot on the game that it's playing, this is what I have so far...

```
else if (message.StartsWith(".updateidle"))
            {
                var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
                var SteamID64 = Bot.SteamClient.SteamID.ConvertToUInt64();
                string htmlget = "http://www.steamcommunity.com/profiles/" + SteamID64 + "/gamecards/" + newgame;
                var doc = webGet.Load(htmlget);

                HtmlNode hoursNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class=\"badge_title_stats_playtime\"]");
                string hours = Regex.Match(hoursNode.InnerText, @"[0-9\.,]+").Value;

                var cards = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("div[@class='badge_title_stats_drops']/span").InnerText;



                if (hours == string.Empty)
                {
                    hours = "0.0";
                }

                Bot.SteamFriends.SendChatMessage(OtherSID, type, "I have been idling for " + hours + " hours on game " + newgame + " and have " + cards + " card drops remaining.");
            }
```

Getting the hours works fine, if the bot has no time on that game, it doesn't appear, so I just check if it's empty then set it to 0.0, however, with the cards, it appears as either "No card drops remaining" or " card drops remaining" which it doesn't get either, I tried using the same method as the hours and only get it if it's a number, and it still returns with "0", same result goes for this...

I also tried again with doing a check if the string is empty, because that could mean there is no card drops remaining, as there would be no numbers, and I also had a look online for methods of getting span data inside a div, or span data general, and neither methods worked, they'd just return with "0". And if you can't already tell, I do have the HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: There is a already an open source program that accomplish what you're trying to do http://www.steamidlemaster.com/

Comment: This is for multiple accounts through SteamBot, which allows for me to still use my main account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So building in my previous answer, that I have decided not to edit, since the followup here is gonna be large. I amusing both Selenium and Html Agility Pack for this. First I log in using Selenium(I am using Mono btw). After that I type in authorize my pc manually(if yours is already authorized then skip this step) and then go to the console and press any key to proceed with getting card info. I will gather the card info for all games in this case. I can't identify which game still has card drops as it has not been implemented yet.

```
class MainClass
{


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userName = "username";
        string password ="password";
        string steamProfile = "steamprofile";
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();


        using (var driver = new FirefoxDriver())
        {

            // Go to the home page
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://store.steampowered.com//login/?redir=0");

            // Get the page elements
            var userNameField = driver.FindElementById("input_username");
            var userPasswordField = driver.FindElementById("input_password");
            //var loginButton = driver.FindElementById("login_btn_signin");
            var loginButton = driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class='btnv6_blue_hoverfade  btn_medium']");

            // Type user name and password
            userNameField.SendKeys(userName);
            userPasswordField.SendKeys(password);

            // and click the login button
            loginButton.Click();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            //Type authorization code and enter manually.

            System.Console.ReadKey();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/"+steamProfile+"/badges");


            driver.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(@"screen.png", ImageFormat.Png); //Debuggin purposes, as I was first using PhantomJS


            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);

            Console.Clear();

        }

        HtmlNodeCollection col = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='progress_info_bold']");

        foreach (HtmlNode n in col)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The output in my case

```
5 of 29 tasks completed
No card drops remaining
No card drops remaining
No card drops remaining
4 card drops remaining
3 card drops remaining
```

This code also gives you the badge progress. You must figure out yourself how to filter your data in Html Agility Pack(read up on [xpath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). I also recommend that you use Selenium, since you can start a steamgame from your webpage using it.

remember that the xpath I gave you in my first answer and is also used in the code above finds ALL("//") the  that has a class that equals "progress_info_bold".

Comment: I tried that method, and it wouldn't work as it required Steam Guard everytime, which I didn't bother setting cookie profiles for, but I realised, that when I was getting the webpage before, the bot wasn't actually logged into the website and that's why it was only getting the hours.

I can get the cookies within SteamBot, but is there a way I can do HtmlDocument.Load(<url>) with cookies? That should hopefully get the page while being logged in.

Comment: I have tried and failed at that, some guy here has made a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33788510/1940851), where he extended the WebClient and Browser class. I don't know if it works(please report back if it does. If you use Selenium you don't have to worry about cookies, Selenium does that for you.

Comment: So, I have tried an awful lot of things to try and get this working, at first I tried my original method with HtmlWeb.Load() but with cookies, and I also tested your method with the Selenium Firefox WebDriver, which wouldn't work as it required SteamGuard, and upon entering it in the browser, it wouldn't redirect to the desired location to web scrape. I read online that you could set up profiles for it which I didn't read about too much as I thought it was a hassle and went back to HTML Agility Pack, which didn't work anymore than your method so I decided to go back to the Selenium method.

Comment: And when I tried using the Selenium method, I tried adding the sessionid, steamlogin and steamloginsecure cookies which would still ask for SteamGuard, so I decided to look into adding profiles to Firefox and changing those in the programs, which worked for preventing SteamGuard, but logging in from the site you referenced, when redirecting to the desired URL I wanted to web scrape from, it would log out again, so I edited the URL it goes to on the browser launch so that after it would log in, it would re-direct straight away to the game's badge page, which would prevent it from logging out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific about what nodes to pick. I highly disencourage you from ever using regex to try and navigate the innertext or innerhtml of an htmldocument.
To find the HTmlNodes regarding if there is anymore cards to drop. try using this xpath:

```
"//span[@class='progress_info_bold']"
```

These nodes will either contain the text:

"No card drops remaining"

or

number+" card drops remaining"

Comment: When I use that xpath instead of the one in my question, I get an error saying "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" rather than it just returning "0". I have gotten this error in the past and assumed it was because I had an incorrect xpath, hence why I didn't mention it in the question.

Comment: This indicates that I have made a mistake. I get off work in two hours. Then I will provide you some working code.

Comment: Are you logged in? You wont be getting the correct HtmlDocument unless you are logged into the website. If you're not then you can't get how many cards remain.

Comment: Yes, if it wasn't logged in, I wouldn't be getting the hours.